# Smart shell script to search for text in file name with error handling

Tags: linux, text, find

I am trying to get a shell script built with some error handling but I have limited knowledge. I am searching for any files with a string say *tests* in it. However if this string is found I would to report an error. I can use the find . -name "**tests**" -print to list the files that contain the string but how do I list the file then report an error in the output if there are results, if it's null then it passes?

Thanks

Comment: so you want to find all files which contain string 'tests' from all locations or a particular location???

Comment: "I should have said searching a particular directory and sub directories"

Answer (score 0):

The manual page has this to say:

> find exits with status 0 if all files are processed
>   successfully, greater than 0   if  errors occur.
>   This is deliberately a very broad
>   description, but if the return value is non-zero,
>   you should  not  rely
>   on the correctness of the results of find.

This is a bit of a conundrum, but if you can be reasonably sure that there will be no unrelated errors, you could do something like

```
find . -name '*tests*' -print -exec false \;
```

If you want the list of found files on standard error, add a redirection `>&2`